# How do I safely grant permission for Cloud Scheduler to create a Dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Dataflow template that I can use for a Dataflow job running as a service account of my choosing. I've actually used one of Google's provided samples: `gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_BigQuery`.

I now want to schedule this using Cloud Scheduler. I've set up my scheduler job like so:
[image]

When the scheduler job runs it errors with `PERMISSION_DENIED`:

```json
{
  "insertId": "1kw7uaqg3tnzbqu",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
    "url": "https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/project-redacted/locations/europe-west2/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs%3A%2F%2Fdataflow-templates%2Flatest%2FGCS_Text_to_BigQuery",
    "jobName": "projects/project-redacted/locations/europe-west2/jobs/aaa-schedule-dataflow-job",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "targetType": "HTTP"
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 403
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
    "labels": {
      "job_id": "aaa-schedule-dataflow-job",
      "project_id": "project-redacted",
      "location": "europe-west2"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-12-16T16:41:17.349974291Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/project-redacted/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-12-16T16:41:17.349974291Z"
}
```

I have no idea what permission is missing or what I need to grant in order to make this work and am hoping someone here can help me.

In order to reproduce the problem I have built a terraform configuration that creates the Dataflow job from the template along with all of its prerequisites and it executes successfully.

In that same terraform configuration I have created a Cloud Scheduler job that purports to execute an identical Dataflow job and it is that which fails with the error given above.

All this code is available at https://github.com/jamiet-msm/dataflow-scheduler-permission-problem/tree/6ef20824af0ec798634c146ee9073b4b40c965e0 and I have created a README that explains how to run it:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the service account needs to be granted roles/iam.serviceAccountUser *on itself*

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "sa_may_act_as_itself" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.sa.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
  member             = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa.email}"
}
```

and roles/dataflow.admin is required also, roles/dataflow.worker isn't enough. I assume that's because `dataflow.jobs.create` is required which is not provided by roles/dataflow.worker (see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#roles for reference)

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "df_admin" {
  role   = "roles/dataflow.admin"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa.email}"
}
```

Here is the commit with the required changes: https://github.com/jamiet-msm/dataflow-scheduler-permission-problem/commit/3fd7cabdf13d5465e01a928049f54b0bd486ed73